# Angular2/Jasmine Expect to be null make browser crash

Tags: unit-testing, angular, crash, jasmine

I'm having some trouble with testing one of my components. The test is as follow :

```
describe('SmpEventsNewCompactEventComponent', () => {

  const specService: SmpSpecService = new SmpSpecService();

  describe('Component rendering', () => {
    let componentInstance: any;
    let componentFixture: ComponentFixture<any>;
    let cssSelector: string;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          MaterialModule.forRoot()
        ],
        declarations: [
          SmpEventsCompactEventComponent,
          SmpEventsAddressComponent
        ],
        providers: [
          { provide: SMP_OT_HELPER, useValue: newOtHelperInstance() },
          DatePipe,
          SmpEventTypeCheckerService,
          SmpLangService
        ]
      });

      componentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(SmpEventsCompactEventComponent);
      componentInstance = componentFixture.componentInstance;
    });

    describe('Global', () => {
      it('GIVEN there are date/time AND address ' +
        'WHEN component loads THEN display event', () => {
          //// TEST ONE
          componentInstance.isEventEnabled = true;
          cssSelector = '.events-compact-event';

          let debugElement = specService.queryDebugElement(
            componentFixture, cssSelector);

          expect(debugElement).not.toBeNull();
        });

      it('GIVEN there are no date/time AND no address ' +
        'WHEN component loads THEN do not display event', () => {
          //// TEST TWO
          componentInstance.isEventEnabled = true;
          //componentInstance.isAddressEnabled = false;
          // componentInstance.isDateEnabled = false;
          cssSelector = '.events-compact-event';

          let debugElement = specService.queryDebugElement(
            componentFixture, cssSelector);

            console.log('--------------', debugElement.nativeElement);
          // expect(debugElement.nativeElement).toBe(null);
          // expect(true).toBe(true);
          expect(debugElement).not.toBeNull();
        });
    });
});
```

The specService.queryDebugElement is as follow :

```
  queryDebugElement(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>, cssSelector: string): DebugElement {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    return fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(cssSelector));
  }
```

Whenever i use the

```
expect(true).toBe(true);
```

or

```
expect(debugElement.nativeElement).toBe(null);
```

or

```
expect(debugElement).not.toBeNull();
```

in the TEST TWO, the tests works or fail normally BUT whenever i use

```
expect(debugElement).toBeNull();
```

The browser used by karma crash (tested with chrome/chromium/PhantomJs) and does not give any clue of what happens. This is a not a simple "expect false to be true" fail, the test context completly crash.

**Do you see anything that could explain this behaviour ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `expect(debugElement).toBeTruthy();` instead of `expect(debugElement).not.toBeNull()` because `not.tobeNull()` might not behave as expected when something goes undefined. If your `debugElement` is undefined it might create problems.

Comment: But do you know how can it crash if debugElement is defined ? Because i would at least expect an error log or something if an element withing debugElement is broken, rather than a browser crash.

Comment: After some more tests, the truthy/falsy never have this problem.

Comment: But i'm still not sure how this could make the whole test suit crash.

Answer (score 7):

Angular's `DebugElement` is a rather complex Object, and Jasmine's `expect` seems to be containing recursive parts (or at least algorithms that are complex enough to need many different function calls)... hence the use of `DebugElement` directly in unit tests not being recommended. It usually ends in deep recursion and memory leaks from browser.

In your case, I would try :

```
let nl: NodeList = componentFixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.events-compact-event');

expect(nl.length).toBeFalsy;
```

This way, you're not using DebugElement, and you're not at risk of having undefined values in your tests (apart from the ones you do need to be undefined). Code coverage and results should be equivalent.

Have a look at this article: https://medium.com/@martatatiana/poor-detective-angular2-browser-crash-and-debugelement-f0a651dbf33

Comment: Thanks Rom for the suggestion, i've just came accross this article a week ago or so. But it's annoying not to be able to use the DebugElement correctly, this feature is pretty nice imo. I'll give your solution a try, see if it can give better results.

Answer (score 2):

Use `expect( Boolean(debugElement) ).toBeTruthy()` instead of

- `expect(debugElement).not.toBeNull()`
- or `expect(debugElement).toBeTruthy()`

Comment: That's a way to fix it, but it feels a bit hacky to me. What i did in the tests since that post was to simply not test directly on debug element but rather on subproperties like debugElement.nativeElement, and all my problems are gone :)

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me: https://medium.com/@martatatiana/poor-detective-angular2-browser-crash-and-debugelement-f0a651dbf33.

It proposes to use `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector` instead of Angular's `debugElement`. I think my problem came in combination with forms.

Comment: Link and contents already covered in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43756120/397817